# Connection between U.S. entry into WW1 and Germans sending Lenin back to Russia

Tags: united-states, germany, world-war-one, russia, lenin

The Germans sent Lenin back to Russia ten days after U.S. entry into WW1. Does anyone know of primary source evidence that the Germans thought of Lenin as a possible way to counter U.S. entry by removing the Russians from the war?

Comment: Doesn't sound like an accident. Of course neither were the Hindenburg Offensives...

Comment: There is no connection. The answer of @sds is correct.

Answer (score 5):

The timing was much more connected to the Russian [February Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_Revolution) than to the [US Declaration of War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1917_United_States_declaration_of_war_on_Germany).

It takes time for such operations to be planned, organized, and carried out; it is unthinkable that it could have been done in few days.
Moreover, it made an eminent sense for the Germans to send the Russian Boleshevik exiles back to Russia regardless of any US policy.

See [the answer to another recent question](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/33675/1979) for more details.

Comment: Imperial Germany had a "German 9th Army problem" in World War 1 just like World War 2 ironically. Both survived too interestingly.